Reconstructing Original String from Partial Strings with Missing Letters
I have a string of length n, let's say "ABCDEFG". The string can have duplicate characters, so "ABCBCAGFH" is also a valid string.
I also have a list of strings that are made from the original string, but are missing one or more letters, for example ["BCDEFG", "ADEFG", "ABC"]. The list can have duplicates and has length m. The letters in the list will always come in the same order as in original string, e.g. letter "D" will always come before "EFG" and after "ABC".
I need to reconstruct the original string using only the strings in the list.
I got to the point where I can extract all substrings, but I'm having trouble putting those substrings in the right place, as can be seen in the example below.
Here is my code in Python:
def reconstruct_string(partial_strings):
    """Reconstructs the original string from a list of partial strings.

    Args:
        partial_strings: A list of partial strings.

    Returns:
        The reconstructed original string, or None if it cannot be restored.
    """

    missing_letters = []
    temp_substring = ""
    result = ""

    for string_1 in partial_strings:
        for string_2 in partial_strings[partial_strings.index(string_1) + 1 : ]:
            for i in range(len(string_1)):
                for j in range(len(string_2)):
                    if string_1[i] == string_2[j]:
                        temp_substring += string_1[i]

                        if string_1[i] in missing_letters:
                            missing_letters.remove(string_1[i])
                        break

                    elif string_1[i] not in string_2 and string_1[i] not in missing_letters \
                        and string_1[i] not in temp_substring:
                        missing_letters.append(string_1[i])
                    
                    elif string_2[j] not in string_1 and string_2[j] not in missing_letters \
                        and string_2[j] not in temp_substring:
                        missing_letters.append(string_2[j])
                        
            result += temp_substring
            print(f"{missing_letters=}\n{temp_substring=}\n{result=}\n")
            temp_substring = ""

# Example usage
temp_solutions = ["ABC", "BCDEFG", "ADEFG"]
result = reconstruct_string(temp_solutions)

The print statement returns:
missing_letters=['A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
temp_substring='BC'
result='BC'

missing_letters=['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'B', 'C']
temp_substring='A'
result='BCA'

missing_letters=['B', 'C', 'A']
temp_substring='DEFG'
result='BCADEFG'

These partial strings come from OCR readings which can be incomplete, so the list of partial strings represent readings made from different angles in hopes of being able to reconstruct the full string.
